# UrhoSharp in Xamarin.Forms as UWP: "Platform implementation is not referenced"

Tags: exception, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, urhosharp

Playing with UrhoSharp for the first time as I would like to add a few simple 3D objects to an app. Generally I like to build and test with Windows apps as they load the quickest without the need for emulators. To learn UrhoSharp I was implementing the sample found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/urhosharp/

The sample runs fine for Android but whenever launching the UWP get the exception: "Platform implementation is not referenced". This happens in this line of code:

```
async void StartUrhoApp()
{
    urhoApp = await urhoSurface.Show<UrhoApp>(new ApplicationOptions(assetsFolder: null) { Orientation = ApplicationOptions.OrientationType.LandscapeAndPortrait });
}
```

Searching the web I found very little with this error. One thing mentioned a timing issue but their solution didn't work and was mentioned for Android anyway. Another thing I found mentioned including the reference in both the PCL and platform app, but it is in both. The Xamarin docs say UrhoSharp is supported in Windows... assuming that doesn't mean prerelease?

Got Xamarin.Forms at 2.3.0.107 and UrhoSharp.Forms at 1.0.557.

Thanks for any ideas on getting around this issue...